# Unable to parse data from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is what my success function looks like from my AJAX call:

```
success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                    $('#thing_select').append("<option>" + data.thing + "</option>");

                });
```

The `console.log` shows the right data and it looks like this:

```
0: Object
thing: "Widget"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
thing: "Horse"
__proto__: Object
```

I'm not getting anything appended for `data.thing`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks good. Can you recreate the problem in a fiddle? My guess is that in making the fiddle you will solve what is probably a simple mistake by yourself.

Comment: If I do `console.log(data[0].thing)`, I get the first (correct) value from the JSON object, but not sure how to translate this to my `each`

Answer (score 0):

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek2qLnk3/1/) does what you need.

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="thing_select">
    <option>value a</option>
</select>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
data = new Object();
data.thing = ["value 1", "value 2"];

$('#thing_select').append("<option>" + data.thing[0] + "</option>");
```

As you can see you simply get the reference from the `select` by its id and append stuff. You'd probably did something wrong while retrieving the `select`.